# SAS proc export to CSV: how to add double quotes

Tags: csv, sas

New to this, so apologies.  I have a file in SAS that I need to export as a CSV and I need to add double quotes to all fields.  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was a little hesitant to answer this based on the lack of evidence of any research effort, but the answer isn't obvious and may be of use to others so I answered anyway.

Comment: It would also be helpful to other users if you could state what target system it is that requires all of those extra quotes in the CSV file.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to create a CSV file from SAS.  Using `proc export` won't wrap every field in double-quotes, so the easiest one that will do this is the `%ds2csv()` macro.  This assumes you have SAS 9.2 or later.  The documentation for it can be found here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002683390.htm

An example of running it:

```
%ds2csv(data=sashelp.retail, runmode=b, csvfile=c:\class.csv);
```

Produces:

```
"Retail sales in millions of $","DATE","YEAR","MONTH","DAY"
"$220","80Q1","1980","1","1"
"$257","80Q2","1980","4","1"
"$258","80Q3","1980","7","1"
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't actually say that this macro will quote every field. I would feel better about using it if SAS would publish the code. The source for the macro is available, but it calls an SCL program (sashelp.webutil.ds2csv.scl) to do the actual work and there is no way to see the SCL code.

Comment: But it necessary quote only TEXT field, but not all. Vote "-"

Comment: @crow16384 Read the question.... and I quote: "and I need to add double quotes to ALL fields". Emphasis on ALL is my own.

Comment: Sorry! It' my fault! Will rise vote up when be possible!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one using data step

```
data _null_;
    file 'data_want.csv' dsd dlm = ',';
    set data_have;
    if _n_ = 1 then put @1 "variables name to input"; /* Add variable names */
    put (_all_) (~);
run;
```

Comment: The `~` modifier adds the quotes. It is documented in the manual page on the PUT statement, LIST mode.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0jcwhe1ofmb49n1xf1q2kc44b0v.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the same result with headers included

```
proc contents data=sashelp.class out=vars(keep=name varnum);run;

proc sql noprint;
    select quote(strip(name)) into :vars separated by '|' from vars
    order by varnum;
quit;

data _null_;
    file 'test.txt' dsd dlm='|';
    set sashelp.class;
    if _n_ = 1 then put %sysfunc(quote(&vars.));
    put (_all_) (~);
run;
```

Comment: I think the user probably wants the headers in quotes also. So use `select quote(trim(name)) into ...` and adjust the put statement to `put %sysfunc(quote(&vars))`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but my 2 pence...

The macro below does not quote numeric values that are formatted to a character value, but it's easy to implement.

```
%macro csvQuoteChars(lib=,dset=,outPath=);

 proc contents data=&lib..&dset out=c(keep=name type) noprint;
 run;

 %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(c));
 %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nlobs));

 data _null_;
  set &lib..&dset;
  file "&outPath\&lib..&dset..csv" dsd;

  %do i=1 %to &nobs;
      %let rc = %sysfunc(fetchobs(&dsid,&i));
      %let vName = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,1));
      %let vType = %sysfunc(getvarn(&dsid,2));
      %put &=vName &=vType;

      %if &vType = 2 %then %do;
          put (&vName) (~) @;
      %end;
      %else %if &vType = 1 %then %do;
          put &vName @;
      %end;

      %if &i = &nobs %then %do;
          put;
      %end;

  %end;

 run;

 %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%mend csvQuoteChars;
%csvQuoteChars(lib=sashelp,dset=class,outPath=d:\temp);
```